# How to draw an ellipse using the ellipse equation?

Tags: c++

```
(x - x0)^2/a^2 + (y - y0)^2/b^2 == 1
```

where (x0, y0) is the centre of the ellipse.

the centre point (x0, y0) is randomly located in the region `[SIZE/4, 3*SIZE/4]x[SIZE/4, 3*SIZE/4]`,
and a, b in the interval `[SIZE/4, SIZE/2]` so that in most cases the complete curves can lie in figure.

I have to print out an ellipse on a X-Y axis of Size 15(0 to 14), using the given information.

I am using `cout` to print '.' on the entire graph, and have to print an ellipse using the given dimensions only on that portion of the graph using 'E'.

I have to use the equation to test which points are inside or outside of the curve.

I have to find the closest points to the curve.
For example, I can start from the center (x0, y0) and keep moving up until
I find a point (x0, y1), such as:

- `(x0 - x0)^2/a^2 + (y1 - y0)^2/b^2 >= 1`
- `(x0 - x0)^2/a^2 + ((y1 - 1)- y0)^2/b^2 <= 1`

Then (x0, y1 - 1) and (x0, y1) are candidates which are points closest to the curve on the line x = x0.

Comment: What are you using for your IO? Just `cout`? Or an IO library like `ncurses`? Also, I think you have a typo in your tags. Should be `ellipse` not `eclipse`. Please read (yes, actually read) [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Well, eclispe is an IDE on which I am writing my code

Comment: Sure, but your choice of IDE likely has no bearing on your solution here. Your solution would work if you were using Eclipse same as XCode.

Comment: there are different forms of the equation, for drawing maybe a `y(x) = ...` is more convenient. The form you have only tells you if a given point (x,y) is on the ellipsis or not, while `y(x) = ..` will allow you to iterate `x` and get the corresponding y. Another form would be `X(t)` where `X = {x,y}` and `t` is some arbitrary parameter

Comment: ...on the other hand, if your graph is on a grid, you could iterate all grid points and use `abs(F(x,y) - 1) < eps` (instead of your `F(x,y) == 1`) to check if a given grid point is part of the ellipsis or not

Comment: Please show the code you do have for this problem. Right now, we don't know if you're an expert programmer or somebody who just heard about C++ yesterday. If you show us the extent of the code you have tried, it helps us narrow down the answers to focus on the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I am asking to help me find the right approach so that I can start coding my program and not for the entire piece of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not going to give you a full solution, but I think I see the general problem you are having. My comments were just some brainstorming. This is how I would actually approach it:

As you are using `cout` to print `.`, you should use a

```
std::array<std::string,N_ROWS> grid;
```

Initialize it properly with `string`s of correct size, and use a function `std::pair<double,double> get_coordinates(int x,int y)` to transform between discrete coordinates and "world coordinates".

To know if a grid point is part of the ellipsis or not, you have to realize that for a discrete grid, the equation

```
(x - x0)^2/a^2 + (y - y0)^2/b^2 == 1
```

will never be satisfied exactly for some grid coordinates `x_i,y_i`. However, this inequality:

```
 (x - x0)^2/a^2 + (y - y0)^2/b^2 < 1
```

tells you if a point `(x,y)` is inside the area of the ellipsis. And if you consider the four neighboring points:

```
x_i,y_i
x_i+1,y_i
x_i,y_i+1
x_i+1,y_i+1
```

then eiter

- all of them are inside -> `grid[x_i][y_i]` is inside of the ellipsis
- none of them is inside -> `grid[x_i][y_i]` is not inside of the ellipsis
- some are inside, some are outside -> `grid[x_i][y_i]` is part of the ellipsis, ie it gets a `.`

(In the last step i used `grid[x_i][y_i]` which should rather be `grid[x_i + 1/2][y_i + 1/2]`, however this just shifts the whole grid by half a pixel and should not matter too much)

PS: in the meantime the question has been edited. It isnt perfeclty clear what is part of the requirements and what is part of your solution, so I don't know if this answer is of any help. I'll just leave it here...

Comment: This good quality answer being accepted (+1 for me) is the proof that the question is actually off topic here.

Comment: In C and C++ the operator `^` does not mean *power*.

Answer (score 2):

First create a class to hold a Point:

```
struct Point 
{
     const int x; 
     const int y;
};
```

Next create a class to hold ellipse parameters and to check if a point is on that ellipse (or inside it):

```
struct Ellipse
{
    const Point center;

    const int a;
    const int b;

    bool is_on_ellipse(Point p) const
    { 
         return std::pow(p.x - center.x, 2) / std::pow(a, 2) + std::pow(p.y - center.y, 2) / std::pow(b, 2) == 1.0;
    }

    bool is_inside_ellipse(Point p) const
    { 
         return std::pow(p.x - center.x, 2) / std::pow(a, 2) + std::pow(p.y - center.y, 2) / std::pow(b, 2) < 1.0;
    }
};
```

Then you can create an ellipse like this:

```
Ellipse e = {{0, 0}, 2, 3};
```

And check if the point is on the ellipse by calling: `e.is_on_ellipse({px, py})`

With C++20 it can be a little more verbose (but easier to verify correctness) :

```
Ellipse e = {.center = {.x = 0, .y = 0}, .a = 2, .b = 3};
//....
e.is_on_ellipse({.x = px, .y = py})
```